# Rotate element 50% on hover in, continue rotating in same direction on hover out (CSS only)

Tags: css

I have a button that I want to rotate 50% when I hover over it, and when I move the cursor away, it rotates back to its original position but going the same direction (in other words, it completes a 360 degree rotation). My code is the standard code for this type of thing except that the rotation goes to 180 degrees and goes back on hover off.

```
.header-popup:hover .link-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.header-popup .link-icon {
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using an extra wrapper. Here is a basic example that you can adapt to your real use case.

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition:0s 1s;
}
.box div {
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(red 50%,blue 0);
  transition:1s;
}
.box:hover {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
.box:hover div{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```